# How to insert using  DataGridView - c# winforms?

Tags: c#

How can I use datagridview to insert data into SQL Server 2005?
Note : Each time I load the datagrid it should be empty .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the onRowAdded event of your grid, when its raised , conneto to you DB and insert the new record into it(use e.RowIndex to find the added row)

Comment: I want to insert on button click

Comment: am I correct? you want to insert data of your gridview into db?yes?